# How to call static class method from a struct?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2008, struct

I've been always avoiding the following in C++ (which I believe is `C++03` used in VS 2008) but now I'm curious if it's possible to do this? Let me explain it with the code.

```
//Definitions.h header file
//INFO: This header file is included before CMyClass definition because
//      in contains struct definitions used in that class

struct MY_STRUCT{
    void MyMethod()
    {
        //How can I call this static method?
        int result = CMyClass::StaticMethod();
    }
};
```

then:

```
//myclass.h header file
#include "Definitions.h"

class CMyClass
{
public:
    static int StaticMethod();
private:
    MY_STRUCT myStruct;
};
```

and:

```
//myclass.cpp implementation file

int CMyClass::StaticMethod()
{
    //Do work
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @gha.st: `error C2653: 'CMyClass' : is not a class or namespace name`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you would need to move the implementation of `MY_STRUCT::MyMethod` outside the header file, and put it somewhere else. That way you can include `Definitions.h` without already having `CMyClass` declared.

So your `Definitions.h` would change to:

```
struct MY_STRUCT{
    void MyMethod();
};
```

and then elsewhere:

```
void MY_STRUCT::MyMethod()
{
    int result = CMyClass::StaticMethod();
}
```

Comment: Well, in that case I won't be able to include its variable in the `CMyClass` class.

Comment: No, just move the method implementation, leave the rest of it in place. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see. Yeah, it works if I add `void MY_STRUCT::MyMethod()` implementation after the `int CMyClass::StaticMethod()` method is defined in the `myclass.cpp` file. It really fragments the code though...

Comment: There's no way to do this with the `extern` keyword, is there?

Comment: No, `extern` is unrelated to this.

Comment: Well, that's not quite true; declaring `void MyMethod();` inside the `struct` definition in the header file serves the same purpose as `extern` would for a non-member function.